# Pickled eggs in a jar. What counts?

Tags: eggs

Do the nutritional facts on the outside of a package reflect the ENTIRE contents of the package or just what it is assumed a consumer would eat?  For example:  a jar of pickles (or pickled eggs) -- do the nutritional facts include the vinegar and brine the pickles (eggs) swim in?

Answer (score 2):

They reflect what is listed as a serving size.  If a serving lists one pickle - then that's what the nutritional info reflects.  If it lists pickle + 1 oz juice (there's no way it does), then it would reflect that.